# Problema com conexao com Firebird 3.0 com Java 1.8

Tags: java, firebird, jdbc

Estou tendo problemas ao tentar efetuar conexão com o Firebird 3.0 utilizando Jaybird 2.2.7, ao realizar o teste com Firebird 2.5 consigo efetuar a conexão com a base de dados, mas ao tentar efetuar com o Firebird 3.0 entra na exceção.

Segue as imagens na entrada da exceção e o erro gerado no teste efetuado com Junit, também segue a imagem com a conexão estabelecida com banco de dados Firebird 2.5

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código fonte utilizando na classe Conexão.

```
package conexaobanco;

public class Conexao {

private static final String URL_DEFAULT = "jdbc:firebirdsql:192.168.0.200:banco_teste";
private static final String USER_DEFAULT = "SYSDBA";
private static final String PASSWORD_DEFAULT = "masterkey";

private static final int REGISTER_CLASS_FOR_NAME = 1;
private static final int REGISTER_PROPERTIES = 2;
private static final int REGISTER_JDBC4 = 3;

private static final int CONNECT_DRIVERMANAGER = 1;
private static final int CONNECT_DRIVER = 2;

public void testMe() {
    String databaseURL = URL_DEFAULT;
    String user = USER_DEFAULT;
    String password = PASSWORD_DEFAULT;

    java.sql.Driver driver = null;
    java.sql.Connection con = null;
    java.sql.Statement stmt = null;
    java.sql.ResultSet rs = null;

    int registrationAlternative = REGISTER_CLASS_FOR_NAME;
    switch (registrationAlternative) {

    case REGISTER_CLASS_FOR_NAME:
        try {
            Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");
        } catch (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Firebird JCA-JDBC driver not found in class path");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        break;


    case REGISTER_PROPERTIES:
        java.util.Properties sysProps = System.getProperties();
        StringBuffer drivers = new StringBuffer("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");
        String oldDrivers = sysProps.getProperty("jdbc.drivers");
        if (oldDrivers != null)
            drivers.append(":" + oldDrivers);
        sysProps.put("jdbc.drivers", drivers.toString());
        System.setProperties(sysProps);
        break;

    case REGISTER_JDBC4:
        break;
    }


    try {
        driver = java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(databaseURL);
        System.out.println("Firebird JCA-JDBC driver version " + driver.getMajorVersion() + "."
                + driver.getMinorVersion() + " registered with driver manager.");
    } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to find Firebird JCA-JDBC driver among the registered drivers.");
        System.out.println(e);
        return;
    }


    int connectionAlternative = CONNECT_DRIVER;
    switch (connectionAlternative) {

    case CONNECT_DRIVERMANAGER:
        try {
            con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, user, password);
            System.out.println("Connection established.");
        } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Unable to establish a connection through the driver manager.");
            System.out.println(e);
            return;
        }
        break;


    case CONNECT_DRIVER:
        try {
            java.util.Properties connectionProperties = new java.util.Properties();
            connectionProperties.put("user", user);
            connectionProperties.put("password", password);
            connectionProperties.put("lc_ctype", "WIN1252");
            con = driver.connect(databaseURL, connectionProperties);
            System.out.println("Connection established.");
        } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Unable to establish a connection through the driver.");
            System.out.println(e);
            return;
        }
        break;
    }

    // Disable the default autocommit so we can undo our changes later
    try {
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("Auto-commit is disabled.");
    } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to disable autocommit.");
        System.out.println(e);
        return;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Possíveis causas:
Tente colocar o caminho do arquivo FDB ao invés de seu 'alias' na URL.
Veja se a porta 3050 está liberada para uso remoto nessa máquina.